# Compare Array values and hash keys. If match, sum corresponding hash values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

For:

```
a = [:product_one, :product_two, :product_three]
h = { product_one: 5, product_two: 9, product_three: 4, 
      product_four: 12, product_five: 20 }
```

I am trying to see if the hash key matches the array value (or should it be the other way around? Do my arrays values match my hash keys?) and then grab the corresponding matching hash values and sum them.

I am thinking in `.select` such as  `h.select {|item| h.has_key?(item)}` but I am stuck with the mathing and suming part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
a.map {|key| h[key] }.compact.reduce(:+)
```

In summary:

- `map` will apply the block to each element in the array
- `h[key]` will return the corresponding value, or nil if none
- `compact` will remove all nil values
- `reduce(:+)` will sum them

Ruby can be quite terse, if not always easy to parse.

Comment: Correct, works perfectly! A small detail though in my specific case, we need to apply `.to_sym` when passing the key to "h", such as: `a.map {|key| h[key.to_sym] }.compact.reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 5):

You can write like:

```
h.values_at(*a).sum
```

Or (for Ruby version < 2.4):

```
h.values_at(*a).inject(:+)
```

Comment: sum on array is rails only for me - in "standard ruby" you have to use inject

Comment: @Martin, its avaliable since ruby 2.4

Comment: Thanks, did not know!

Comment: Indeed, when testing, `.sum` is undefined method

Comment: @BorisSB, I wrote what you can do if your ruby version < 2.4.0